# UIImageView not showing the background View if the image has transparent regions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, transparency

I have a `UIView` has some labels and buttons on it.

Next I also have a image which has a square area that is transparent, now 
if I create a `UIImageView` and add this image which has transparent regions I am not able to see the background view (which has buttons and labels) through this transparent image.

If I play with the alpha value that doesn't work as intended which is to see the transparent regions exactly as it would have appeared on the `UIView` which has the labels and buttons.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TI1.jpg"];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Also I would be interested to know if there is other way to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Basically I want to highlight a certain area of the view which has buttons/labels and make the rest of the area greyed out. My idea was to have this `UIImageView` with transparent regions in image to achieve that.

Thanks
Ankur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `imageView.opaque = NO;`

UIImageView inherits from UIView. According to that class's docs:

> This property provides a hint to the drawing system as to how it
>   should treat the view. If set to YES, the drawing system treats the
>   view as fully opaque, which allows the drawing system to optimize some
>   drawing operations and improve performance. If set to NO, the drawing
>   system composites the view normally with other content. The default
>   value of this property is YES.

Also, not sure that JPG even supports transparency, so try exporting the image as a PNG to ensure you get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, so it was my jpeg image that was the problem. I did change the value of imageView.opaque = NO;